# How to Get Synchronus in Asynchronus Call (Ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax

My Browser shows deprecation warning, when i do ajax call. I need the script to wait for the feedback before the value can be stored in variable for next progress

Here's my chunck of code:

```
    url='https://data.com/txt';
    var templastprice=0;
    var tempvalue=0;
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            templastprice=data['ticker']['last'];
            tempvalue=="0";

          },
          async: false
    });
```

I don't think this is a good approach for the future, any suggestion to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: 1) put ur next progress inside success callback. 2) use promises 3) use async await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JQuery deferred.promise https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/ or queue, aynch, flow js to make synchronous calls. Similar answers can be found at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)